# Error while sending email from symfony mailer via aws ses

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-ses, symfony-mailer

My controller which is suitable for sending emails looks like this:

```php
class MailerController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/email")
     */
    public function sendEmail(MailerInterface $mailer): Response
    {
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from('hello@example.com')
            ->to('you@example.com')
            ->subject('Time for Symfony Mailer!')
            ->text('Sending emails is fun again!')

        $mailer->send($email);

        // ...
    }
}
```

After visiting `/email` I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "XXX" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException: Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Authentication Credentials Invalid"
```

My mailer config looks like this:

```yaml
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: 'smtp://XXX:YYY@email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:465'
```

I would like to add that I XXX and YYY are AWS credentials obtained from
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dsfT.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by installing a new lib `composer require symfony/amazon-mailer` and use `ses+api`

But make sure to urlencode any special characters that you have in your secret key.

Example:

```
ses+smtp://$AWS_MAILER_USER:$WS_MAILER_PASSWORD@default?region=eu-west-1
```

Another option is trying with `async-aws/ses` package.

Comment: After applying your changes I am getting the error: `Could not reach the remote Amazon server.`. I am using `symfony/amazon-mailer: 4.4.*`, maybe I should add in `dsn` string some info about port or url to smpt server

Comment: And why I cannot use plain smtp protocol?